# Rendering a js.erb file during form submission ajax Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a form which looks like this:

```
<div class= "parent-container">
  <%= form_with scope: @company, url: companies_path, html: { class: "form-inline", remote: true, "data-type" => :js, id: "new-company-create" }, local: true do |f| %>
    <div class= "form-group">
      <%= f.label :nil, 'Company Name:', :class => 'sr-only'%>
      <%= f.text_field :nil, :class => 'form-control-plaintext' %>
    </div> 
    <div class="form-group mx-sm-3"> 
      <%= f.label :name, 'Enter a Company Name :   ' %> 
      <%= f.text_field :name, :class => 'form-control large-input-grp', :placeholder => "Enter any Company Name" %>     
    </div>
    <%= button_to "Create a Company", companies_path, class: "btn btn-default", id: "create_company_main", :type => "submit", :method => "post"%>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

which I'm trying to submit via ajax Rails and realised what a pain a simple process can be.

In my controller, the form posts to this method:

```
def create
    @newCompany = Company.new(company_params) 
    respond_to do |format|
    if @newCompany.save
      format.js
      format.html { render :nothing => true, :notice => 'Company created successfully!' }
      format.json { render json: @newCompany, status: :created, location: @newCompany }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @newCompany, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
    end     
end
```

and I have tried multiple combinations in the `respond_to do |format|` block, but nothing seems to be working.

Nothing that I do, seems to be returning me the _create.js.erb file instead looking for an HTML.

In my terminal, I can see the following being displayed during the post request:

```
Processing by CompaniesController#create as HTML
```

The tutorials that I could see regarding this are all outdated and I am trying to understand rails step by step but I'm stuck at something so basic as this.

Don't really understand why I have to do `format.html` and `format.json` even though I want a JS file from the controller and how do I get the js.erb file from the controller.

Comment: why do you need to mention `"data-type" => :js` when you have alredy mentioned `remote: true` ?

Comment: I was trying out different options. Keeping only remote: true didn't work.

Comment: `remote: true` should not be in `html`, but be passed directly as *form_with* param, like `url: companies_path`.

Comment: Rails will handle it and set the `data-remote` attribute on the form.

Comment: It doesn't. It only sets the remote = "true" if I pass it inside the html hash.
I am using Rails 5

Comment: That's what I'm saying, don't pass it into the *html* hash, but as a *form_with* param like *url* and *local*.

Comment: It doesn't work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its sending html request because you have mentioned link on your submit button which behaves as `<a href="/compaines">Create a Company</a>`, and it is hitting your action without submitting your form .

Try this: -

```
<%= form_for(@company, url: companies_path_path, :html => { class: "form-inline", id: "new-company-create" },remote: true, method: 'POST') do |f| %>
   <div class= "form-group">
    <%= f.label :nil, 'Company Name:', :class => 'sr-only'%>
    <%= f.text_field :nil, :class => 'form-control-plaintext' %>
  </div> 
  <div class="form-group mx-sm-3"> 
    <%= f.label :name, 'Enter a Company Name :   ' %> 
    <%= f.text_field :name, :class => 'form-control large-input-grp', :placeholder => "Enter any Company Name" %>     
  </div>

  <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-default", id: "create_company_main") do %>
    Create a Company
  <% end %>
<%end%>
```

Comment: i made some changes, please have a look again, 
its sending html request because you have mentioned link on your submit button.
please try this new code, hopefully it will send ajax request to your controller

Comment: So adding the link in Submit button was the answer, you should update that on your answer. Thank you so much btw!

Comment: Everything were good with your form , but your submit button was behaving like a external link, which goes to create action of controller without submitting  your form. answer updated , thank you. :)